# How to create a Circular row in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

After a lot of searches, I still can't create a Circular Row Like the Image below. this screenshot is from MetaTrader4.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html

Comment: And I think this is similar to what you are looking for: https://pub.dev/packages/circle_list

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a `CustomMultiChildLayout`.

Look at this tutorial on how to use it: https://medium.com/hackernoon/how-to-create-custom-layout-widgets-in-flutter-d9419312a9bd.